# Mule does not create consumers in some queues on Rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, mule

I'm working on mule 3.5, rabbitmq connector 3.6 and RabbitMQ 3.6.0 When I deploy my application, mule does not create some consumers on my queues, but if I redeploy my app in multiple times it would create all of listeners completely.
Here is part of my code:
Amqp connector:

```
<amqp:connector name="amqpRabbitMQConnector" host="${rabbitmq.host}" username="${rabbitmq.username}" password="${rabbitmq.password}" validateConnections="true" requestedHeartbeat="60"  activeDeclarationsOnly="true">          
<reconnect-forever frequency="2000" blocking="false"/>  
</amqp:connector>
```

Inbound endpoint:

```
<amqp:inbound-endpoint queueName="${queue.businessSearchRequest}" exchange-pattern="one-way"connector-ref="amqpRabbitMQConnector"/>
```

Outbound endpoint:

```
<amqp:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="amqpRabbitMQConnector" exchangeName="${exchange.bizSearchResponse}"                             exchangeType="topic" exchangeDurable="true" routingKey="${core.routing.key}"/>
```

Actually, my exchanges bound to my queues in rabbitmq and I can see that the exchange put message to the queue and the queue depth increases but in rabbitmq browser there is no consumer which listens to the queue hence, mule can not process it.

Comment: Hi, I think you need to provide more details like Mule version connector version, your flow configuration files and so on. Otherwise will be hard to help you.

Comment: Of course, you're right. My mule version is 3.5.0, amqpconnector is 3.6.2 and this is my connector:

Comment: @MauroRocco Hi, you're right. This is my connector code: <amqp:connector name="amqpRabbitConnector" host="${host}" username="${username}" password="${pass}" validateConnections="true" requestedHeartbeat="60" activeDeclarationsOnly="true">
     <reconnect-forever frequency="2000" blocking="false"/>
</amqp:connector>

Comment: Hi @Sima, first of all I suggest you edit your question so people will better read it. Second you are showing me the connector conf only but what about inbound and outbound message processor where you normally put queue names and so son. The best will be to copy and past the full xml of your flow.

Comment: @MauroRocco Actually I'm new to stackoverflow, but I did my best :), hope it be informing enough

Comment: Hi, Sadly this does not let understend your information flow and therefore makes difficult to help you. Try to answer this questions: 1) How you know you don't have any consumer running ? Have you tried posting message in the queue via RabbitMQ management interface directly ? 
2) The producer flow is posting to a specific exchange while the consumer is creating a queue on the default amqp exchange, is this the behaviour your want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some of queues listeners registered before AmqpMessageReceiver initializes. I changed my xml orders and the problem solved.